# The requested URL returned error 502, corporate?

Tags: git, git-clone

Does anyone know what the problem seems to be with `git`? 
I am getting this error when running running a `git clone` to clone from `team foundation server` (tfs).

```
 fatal: unable to access 'http://website.com/_git/project': The requested URL returned error: 502
```

Comment: It is most likely an issue with the configuration of your proxy or the URL you are using. It's not something we can troubleshoot from here, because it's not an issue with a site we can access. Ask your supervisor to help you with the issue. We can't help you with an issue you have accessing a web page (unless that page is located at [se] somewhere, in which case you should be asking for help in [meta] or [meta.se]).

Comment: Any idea why the exact same url would work for my supervisor and not for me? We have tried to troubleshoot this issue for the past couple of hours now with no success :(

Comment: Yes. A difference in the proxy settings, a difference in the URL you're using, your gateway to the server, or a configuration issue on the server itself (not git) which (as I said previously) is nothing we can troubleshoot from here. The issue is with your route to that server, and we have no access to the information about your network or routing. If your supervisor can't help, get your IT department involved.

Comment: Okay thank you I will show them this post!

Answer (score 11):

This took me considerable amount of time to troubleshoot and fix this annoying issue.

In my case I had the **http_proxy** and **https_proxy** environment variables set on my PC. ( You can find them under control panel - System and Security - Advanced system settings - Env variables - System variables section bottom panel in windows 10)

Once I deleted those 2 environment variables ( highlight - delete - ok ) and closed the Git-Terminal window and re-opened it the problem (http 502) went away. Just to confirm I tested with Git GUI + VS Code + Git Term. Did git fetch/clone/push/etc ...

**Note**: I am in a corporate env behind a strict proxy but so is the Enterprise tfs URL therefore I do not need a proxy interfering between me and my tfs server. I suspect (cannot confirm or rule out) the proxy was playing a MITM. Client machine is Windows 10 latest build running git version **2.22.0.windows.1**

Answer (score 10):

For reference: Within a corporate environment behind an authenticating proxy server I had previously edited my git global config an override for the proxy server.  Once I corrected this, I was able to connect.

Useful command:

```
git config --global --list


[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
[user]
        name = GuyWicks
[user]
        email = guy.wicks@iworkhere.com
[http]
    proxy = http://public-cache:8080

[https]
    proxy = http://public-cache:8080
```

I commented out the four proxy lines (#)

Answer (score 7):

I was running into the same issue. For some reason I had http and Https proxies set up in my git config list. Removing those allowed me to clone successfully.

Answer (score -2):

I have also met this issue when cloning a project from our private gitlab repo. Initially I am using the following command:

```sh
git clone http://remote_gitlab_url/user_name/some_projects
```

I am seeing the following error:

> The requested URL returned error: 502

After adding `.git` to the project name, everything works smoothly:

```sh
git clone http://remote_gitlab_url/user_name/some_projects.git
```